# How do we prove that the double cone is not manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Prove that:

$$Z:=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2 +y^2-z^2=0\right\}$$

is not a manifold (even not a topological manifold).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I assume $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3$? or $\in \Bbb C^3$?

Comment: I mean in $R^3$

Answer (score 3):

$Z\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ is not connected - that can only happen with 1-dimensional manifolds. But a neighbourhood of e.g. $(1,0,1)$ clearly looks 2-dimensionsl.